# Get object count in Ruby PageObject

Tags: ruby, webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a page, which is the list of several other elements.
I want to create page object for this page, and have an ability to count those list objects and perform some action with object by it's counter.

So now I have a class, which looks like this

```
class Feed
  attr_accessor :instance
  include PageObject

  link(:all_feed_items, :xpath => "//*[@id='newsList']/div/div/div[1]/a")
end
```

So for example first feed item have xpath like

```
//*[@id='newsList']/div/div/div[1]/a[1]
```

Second:

```
//*[@id='newsList']/div/div/div[1]/a[2]
```

etc

How can I get item with similar xpath by its number in Page-object?

Comment: The question is then, how to replace `[1]` with variable?

Comment: I can do it, but I think this not gonna work well with all this 'page-object' methology

Comment: If you know how to do it, share the code, so we can comment.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this will work:

```
class Feed
  attr_accessor :instance
  include PageObject

  select_list(:news_list, :id => 'newsList')
  link_elements(:all_feed_items) do | page |
    news_list_element.div_element.div_element.div_element.link_elements
  end
end
```

This will generate a method that will return all of the links in an array.